# apt-get very slow after downloads

Tags: 14.04, server, apt

I have a Open VZ based Ubuntu 14.04 minimal VPS with 4 cores and 2 gb RAM.

When I try to install anything it downloads very fast as it should but then it takes forever after all the gets.

```
Preparing to unpack
Unpacking  
Processing triggers
Setting up
```

Each one of these steps when updating apt-utils took 2-3 minuets. The get took less than a second.

Is there anything I can do or change to improve this? On my local server I don't even have time to read these lines before its done.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 34.888 s, 30.8 MB/s
```

Comment: Those steps (and the rest of the process, most likely) are more bound by I/O than CPU. What is the backing storage medium?

Comment: RAID 10. nodeserve.com is the provider. Are there any good I/O tests I could run to confirm?

Comment: Something like `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1024` will test the read speed for the first gigabyte of the drive. (Hopefully I didn't destroy my drive.)

Comment: I ran `dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync` and came back with 30.8 MB/s. That seems slow to me.

Comment: My USB drive gets 33

Comment: Considering  that I get 72 MB/s with `dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=64k count=16k` on a basic 5400 RPM hard drive, I agree that something's odd with your I/O.

Comment: @saiarcot895 If youd like to post an answer to the affect of your comments I will select it as the official answer.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I have tried some more testing and concluded that the issue is caused by an issue with the provider. The storage I/O is not preforming properly. Less than 30 MB/s.

The provider has been notified.

Comment: Please use the [edit link](http://askubuntu.com/posts/607398/edit) on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This is a complete answer, My slow Apt problem is due to slow I/O rates. Since the I/O rate is out of my control I have contacted the provider. If this was my own VM host this would still be the answer to my question and I would maybe be asking new questions about fixing the I/O issues.